# Automating makefile for all files in a certain directory

Tags: makefile

I have a folder (`./tests/`) that contains a bunch of c files, `a.c`, `b.c`, `d.c`, ..., `y.z`, `z.c`. They all contain a `main` function. I want to write a Makefile that will compile all of the files in that directory independently. Something like this:

```
test_a: ./tests/a.c $(STUFF)
    gcc $< $(STUFF) $(OTHERSTUFF)

test_b: ./tests/b.c $(STUFF)
    gcc $< $(STUFF) $(OTHERSTUFF)

test_c: ./tests/c.c $(STUFF)
    gcc $< $(STUFF) $(OTHERSTUFF)

test_d: ./tests/d.c $(STUFF)
    gcc $< $(STUFF) $(OTHERSTUFF)

...


test_z: ./tests/z.c $(STUFF)
    gcc $< $(STUFF) $(OTHERSTUFF)
```

The only difference between all of these targets is the letter in the target name (`test_X`), and the letter in the first prerequisite (`./tests/X.c`), which is the same `X`. So, how could I automate this process so that I dont need to copy and paste the same target a bunch of times?

Comment: Which `make` implementation do you use? GNU, POSIX, BSD, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU make, it's pretty simple:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard tests/*.c)
TARGETS := $(notdir $(SRCS:.c=))

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): $(STUFF)

test_%: tests/%.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(OTHERSTUFF)
```

Comment: What does the `$(TARGETS): $(STUFF)` do?

Comment: In your sample, you added `$(STUFF)` as a prerequisite to each target: `test_a: ./tests/a.c $(STUFF)`.  So, that line adds `$(STUFF)` as a prerequisite for all the targets in the `$(TARGETS)` variable.